# Open Xbap page in firefox

Tags: wpf, firefox, xbap

I need to open xbap page using firefox 6, how can I do that? What plugins do I need to use?
Each time I open it -> download window pop up !!

Comment: How about [MSDN: Firefox Add-ons to Support .NET Application Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716877.aspx)

Comment: @Pekka: XAML Browser APp. The thing before Silverlight killed it.